# How to retrieve from a local offline OLAP cube the MDX query that generated it?

Tags: mdx, cube, cubes, olap-cube

Any offline cube actually contains the MDX statement that generated it, how can i retrieve it's CREATE and INSERT queries?

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe that this is saved anywhere in the .cub file. I think your only option is to compare the offline cube to the server cube to reverse engineer the statement that would have been run.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think .CUB files save this information as many are created without any MDX at all. If you want the MDX created by a process, you need to grab it there an then.